# Javascript Function to Autoplay Random HTML Audio After Delay

Tags: javascript, audio, random

I am trying to write some javascript code with some jQuery that will play a random sound file (selected from an array) to play periodically by setting a random amount of time to delay between sounds. So far, I have gotten the random song selector to work. However, there seems to be an issue with the recursion in the playMusic function. Only two songs will play back-to-back then stop with no delay between the songs.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var randInterval = 0;
            var songList = ["song1","song2","song3","song4","song5"];
            var songHTML;

            function getRandomSong(){
                var randSong = songList[Math.floor(Math.random()*songList.length)]; 
                songHTML = "<source src='music/" + randSong + ".mp3'>" + 
                               "<source src='music/" + randSong + ".ogg'>";
                return songHTML;
            }

            function setRandomInterval(){
                randInterval = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+60); 
                return randInterval;
            }

            function playMusic(){
                var delayTime = setRandomInterval();
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#myAudio').html(getRandomSong());
                    $('#myAudio').prop("volume", 0.05);
                    $('#myAudio').get(0).play();            
                });
                $('#myAudio').on('ended', function(){
                    $('#myAudio').delay(delayTime).queue(function(){
                        return playMusic();
                    });
                }); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="playMusic()">
        <div>
            <audio controls id="myAudio" autoplay>
            </audio>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) delays in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the delay issue. However, I am still having a problem with the recursion of the function. I want it to continuously play song, delay, play song, delay, etc.

Comment: Try taking the event binding outside of the playMusic function

Comment: Thanks, apparently I was having a senior moment. I needed an event handler instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. Below is the code that works correctly. I removed any JQuery related code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var randInterval = 0;
            var songList = ["song1","song2","song3","song4","song5"];
            var myAudio = new Audio("music/" + songList[Math.floor(Math.random()*songList.length)] + ".mp3");

            //Generates a random song, sets it attributes/properties, and 
            //appends a file extension that works with the browser.
            function getRandomSong(){
                var randSong = songList[Math.floor(Math.random()*songList.length)]
                if (myAudio.canPlayType('audio/mp3;')) {
                    myAudio.src="music/" + randSong + ".mp3";
                } else {
                    myAudio.src="music/" + randSong + ".ogg";
                }
                myAudio.id="myAudio";
                myAudio.volume=0.15;
                myAudio.load();
                myAudio.controls=false
                myAudio.preload=false;
            }

            //Sets a random interval for the setTimeout Function with the
            //'variation' parameter being a random amount of time in 
            //seconds, and the 'range' parameter being a set amount of time 
            //in seconds.
            function getRandomInterval(variation, range){
                randInterval = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000*variation)+(1000*range)); 
                return randInterval;
            }   

            //Gets a random song and plays that song.
            function playMusic(){
                getRandomSong();
                myAudio.play();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Plays music on page load.
            playMusic();

            //Event Listener that will start a new song after a pause
            //of randomly determined length.
            myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function(){setTimeout(function(){playMusic();}, getRandomInterval(2,2));}, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```